# log4j2 changing configuration during runtime - already supported or custom class needed?

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm new to logging and wanted to use slf4j with log4j2 in a project of mine.
The configuration is using a json file.

I know that you can create a configuration during runtime with a ConfigurationFactory or use a file that will be checked if it has changed every time a log statement is made and a given time (or none) has passed.

My question is regarding the json file. Will i have to write my own class to change that file using a json parser or will slf4j/log4j2 change the file for me somehow? If so how?

I was reading through the documentation and googled, but didn't find the answer.

I hope you can help me out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First write you code against the slf4j API.  It's mostly a bunch of interfaces, and you don't want to "pollute" your code with non-slf4j API if you're using the slf4j logging interface.

Then you want to package / run with log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.jar which adapts the slf4j API to the log4j2 API.  Then you can configure your log4j2 system like you would if you never used slf4j.

Do not use the log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.jar, as that is intended to make code written to log to log4j loggers put their logging on the slf4j API, and if slf4j then implements that with a slf4j logger, your logging events will be passed between slf4j and log4j in an endless loop.

---- Editing post to address question, as it would be too much to put in a comment ----

slf4j is a logging suite with three main kinds of components.

1. A set of "input adapters" that take one logging system and pipe it into the slf4j API.
2. An slf4j API that doesn't make any assumptions about how logging is implemented.
3. A set of "output adapters" that take the slf4j API calls and cram them into some "other" logging system.

The input adapters typically have names like "logsystem-to-slf4j-version.jar", and should be used when you want to migrate to slf4j but haven't rewritten your code to stop using the "old" logging interface.

The output adapters typically have names like "logsystem-slf4j-impl-version.jar" and only one should be provided to slf4j at runtime.

Because slf4j is unaware of which logging adapter it might use to actually process the log messages, it is unaware of the configuration capabilities of that logging system.

Even worse, while logging typically has a semi-similar interface for the submission of log messages, they have vastly different interfaces for configuring the handling of such messages.

In short, if slf4j only adapts the handling of log messages, not the handling of configuration (which is vastly different between say System.out.println(...) and log4j)

This means that at best, you can filter your log messages at the slf4j API layer; but, there is no guarantee that they will be presented; because the underlying logging implementation may be configured to filter even more messages, or may be replaced with a "no logging at all" implementation.

Comment: slf4j doesn't address dynamic configuration of logging, as that would require slf4j to know the configuration details of the underlying logging implementation, and such a thing is generally classified as a "leaky abstraction" which is a software programming term that real world programs attempt to avoid (for many very good reasons).

Comment: I thought the configuration is exempt from the slf4j interface? So did i misunderstand that? The slf4j documentation isn't very helpful when compared to other docs. I'm sorry. :(

Edit: Just read your comment. So basically i will need to configure the loggers with the log4j config file, as i thought. Log4j already parses the json file to its configuration at runtime. My question was if log4j provides a way to write to the json file or if i should implement my own class (using a parser) that handles writing to it to change the config at runtime?

Comment: Regarding your new edit:
You are not really answering my question. I guess I'm not expressing myself well enough.
Does log4j (not slf4j) have a way to write into the config file it is using to configure itself (in my case log4j2.json".
Example: Log4J.logLevel("info") -> log4j writes that change to the configuration file, so that the configuration change is also there when you start the application the next time.If not i would write my own class that makes the change to the configuration. As in: CustomClass.changeLogLevel("warn"); Log4j2 automatically checks if the config file has been changed.

Comment: Generally log4j doesn't have a way to rewrite the configuration file (unless it's been added and I'm unaware) however, it has a way to "configure from the source code" which permits you to effectively do the same thing, provided you are writing source code that depends directly on log4j (which robs the ability to swap out logging implementations easily, which is what slf4j provides).  Logging levels are filtered in many locations, so setting the Class-level filter won't make your log appear if it is also discarded at the Output-level.

Comment: Ok thanks. :)

So basically if i want to change log level in my application's properties window I will have to read parse change write the json data myself. hm

Comment: Why bother with the file?  Just configure to the default in the application, and then reconfigure that from the property window.

Comment: Because most log4j2 guides i read mentioned, that the cleaner way of configuring log4j2 would be to use a config file. However since I will need to write my own LoggerConfiguration class (to have a clean interface between log4j2 and my application) i might as well use the configuration method without the file.

Comment: @JohnRW I think you've got it!

Answer (score 0):

Within some bounds it is possible to have log4j2 react on runtime values: With properties (which can grab entries from System config or ThreadContext), it's simple enough to inject some dynamism.

Comment: This only works if you assume a specific logging implementation.  If you do, then the question is, why write to an API meant to abstract the logging implementation, as the moment you switch implementations, you'll break your code as it requires both the abstraction and the specific implementation?  That's a leaky abstraction, and while it is possible (reflection, etc.) it is not possible for all scenarios, and even harder to do if you really want to be able to swap out logging systems.

Comment: Log4j2 checks if the configuration file has changed every time a new log is to be created + a set amount of time (monitorInterval). What I'm trying to ask is if log4j has an api-call, that changes the configuration in its config file (Basically a parse back to the file instead of just parse json for reading purposes) or if I need to write that "config changer"-class myself